# Find the $n$-th power of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Let $z=1+2i$ be a complex number.

Prove that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, the number $z^n$ has the following form: $a_n+ib_n$, with $a_n,b_n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I guess the solution lies in the trigonometric form of $z$. However, I get a really ugly number trying to transform $z$ into its trigonometric form.

I would really appreciate if I would get some help on this problem.

Comment: Do you just want to prove that "for any $n \in \Bbb N^*$, the real part and the imaginary part of $z^n$ are both integers", or did you want to prove something more specific about the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$? In the former case, induction is the easiest way, I'd say.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is about finding the sequences denoted by $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Comment: Well, you get $\theta=\arctan 2=\arcsin\frac{2\sqrt 5}{5}=\arccos\frac{\sqrt 5}{5}$. Not much to do about it, I fear. Perhaps working out the coeffficients dierctly in real-imaginary coordinates does something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it by induction:

For the base case is trivial that $1,2\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then suppose that for $k$ you have that $a_{k},b_{k}\in \mathbb{Z}$. Finally, to prove the last step, check that

$$(1+2i)(a_{k}+ib_k)=(a_k-2b_k)+i(b_k+2a_k)$$

So $a_{k+1}=a_k-2b_k$ and $b_{k+1}=b_k+2a_k$ where both are integers.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to prove is that complex numbers with integer real and imaginary parts are closed under multiplication and the result follows from there. i.e. if $a,b,c,d$ are integers then:

$$(a+bi)(c+di)$$

Forms a complex number with integer real and imaginary parts.